# Proving a piece-wise function is bijective

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Suppose the function $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is defined as

$$f() = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle x+1, &  \le 4 \\
x-2, &  \ge 5 \\
\end{cases}$$

I started by showing that it's injective for $x \le 4$ and $x \ge 5$ by showing that $()=(y)$.

Then, I showed that it is surjectve this way:

$$f(x) = x+1 \implies x = n - 1$$

Since $(n-1) \le 4, f(n-1) = (n-1) + 1  = n$

Same logic for the second case...

Am I doing the right thing? I always get confused when it comes to piece-wise functions!

Answer (score 1):

Showing injective for each piece is not sufficient.

$$f(3)=3+1$$

$$f(6)=6-2$$

What can you conclude about whether the function is injective or bijective?

To verify surjectivity, pick any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, try to find a preimage.

You might want to consider cases such as case $1$: $x \leq  5$ and case $2$: $x > 5$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I showed its surjectivity by considering the inverse functions. So for case 1, I said x = y-1. Therefore, f(y-1) in case 1 gives the following: (y-1) + 1 = y.

Comment: hi, which part is the part that you are not sure what I mean? injective part or surjective part?

Comment: For the surjective part, notice that showing each piece of function has an inverse function does not indicate that it is a surjective function.  For example, I can change the question to $$f() = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle x+1, &  \le 4 \\
x\color{blue}+2, &  \ge 5 \\
\end{cases},$$  and $6$ would not have a preimage.

Comment: 1) f:Z→Z, f(x)=x+1, x<=4

For f(x) to be surjective it must be the case that every y∈Z can be written as y=f(x) for some x, x = n -1, so case 1 is surjective

Comment: btw, what is the original question, is it to check if a function is a bijection?

Comment: Determine the inverse of the function , or else show why  has no inverse

Comment: Do you $f$ has an inverse?